# $\frac{g(x)}{f^*(x)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}s_nx^n$ generates recursion

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

I need help proving that in $\mathbb{F}_q$, if $g$ is a polynomial of degree less than $k$ and $f^*(x)=1-(a_{k-1}x+\dots+a_0x^k)$ a polynomial of degree $k$, then $$\frac{g(x)}{f^*(x)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}s_nx^n$$ fulfills the recursion $s_{n+k}=a_{k-1}s_{n+k-1}+\dots+a_1s_{n+1}+a_0s_n$.

I know that this is all related to LFSRs, but cannot see how to prove the result.

Comment: What is $g$? It can't just be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, otherwise one couldn't expect to find a recursion for the coefficients $\{s_n\}_{n\geq 0}$

Comment: The recursion is fine as the coefficients of $g$ vanish for the indices greater than $k.$ Just multiply the series with $f^*$ and determine the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!